# Set a pointer to a field using reflection

Tags: go

i have the following struct, and need some of the fields to be nulluble so i use pointers, mainly to handle sql nulls

```
type Chicken struct{
    Id                int         //Not nullable
    Name              *string     //can be null
    AvgMonthlyEggs    *float32    //can be null
    BirthDate         *time.Time  //can be null
}
```

so when i do the following i can see that the json result can have nulls for value types which is what i want

```
stringValue:="xx"
chicken := &Chicken{1,&stringValue,nil,nil}
chickenJson,_ := json.Marshal(&chicken)
fmt.Println(string(chickenJson))
```

but when i try to do it all using reflection

```
    var chickenPtr *Chicken
    itemTyp := reflect.TypeOf(chickenPtr).Elem()
    item  := reflect.New(itemTyp)
    item.Elem().FieldByName("Id").SetInt(1)
    //the problem is here not sure how to set the pointer to the field
    item.Elem().FieldByName("Name").Set(&stringValue) //Error caused by this line
    itemJson,_ := json.Marshal(item.Interface())
    fmt.Println(string(itemJson))
```

what i get from the reflection part is the following error

```
cannot use &stringValue (type *string) as type reflect.Value in argument to item.Elem().FieldByName("Name").Set
```

what am i doing wrong?

here is a GoPlay http://play.golang.org/p/0xt45uHoUn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[reflect.Value.Set](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set) only accepts `reflect.Value` as an argument. Use `reflect.ValueOf` on your stringValue:

```
item.Elem().FieldByName("Name").Set(reflect.ValueOf(&stringValue))
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/DNxsbCsKZA.