# Set struct field which is a pointer using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

My question is like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890732/set-a-pointer-to-a-field-using-reflection) but with a slight difference that my value is an `interface{}`.

Let assume we have a struct like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID         int
    Email      string
    ResourceID *int
}
```

and a function that sets values of input struct.

```golang
func setFieldValue(s interface{}, fieldName string, value interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem()
    fieldVal := v.FieldByName(fieldName)

    if fieldVal.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        // Here is the problem
        fieldVal.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&value))
    } else {
        fieldVal.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
    }
}
```

It is obvious that if I run the code I get the following error:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type *interface {} is not assignable to type *int
```

here is the code in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VUoyRras8SD

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try `reflect.ValueOf(value).Addr()`

Comment: try that too, and get `reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value`

Comment: Please post how you call `setFieldsValue()`.

Comment: Can you please make a snippet on https://play.golang.org/ ?

Comment: @Behzadsh in that case try this: https://play.golang.com/p/p6ONzpNgyoA

Comment: @icza  sorry, forgot to add the link to playground

Comment: @edkeveked seems like it worked

Comment: The field value has type "pointer to int". This means you need to create an actual instance of type "int" (holding some `int` value, probably zero) and use its *address* to set the field. There are multiple ways to achieve that, indcluding the one in mkopriva's comment.